# searched content cannot retrieved in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I' new in elastic search.I index some content in elastic search after I trying to search the content it will shows all the content in elastic search  index the search algorithm may not be apply. The mappings fields are  mentioned below.

```
    {
                      "groupId": {
                          "type": "integer",
                          "index": "not_analyzed"

                      },
                      "createrId": {
                      "type": "integer",
                          "index": "not_analyzed"
                      },
                      "name": {
                          "type": "string",
                          "index": "not_analyzed"
                      },
                      "comments": {
                          "type": "string",
                          "index": "not_analyzed"
                      },
                      "createdOn": {
                          "type":"date","format":"date_optional_time", "index":    "not_analyzed"
                      },
                      "status": {
                          "type": "integer",
                          "analyzer":"keyword_lowercase"
                      },
                      "description": {
                          "type": "string",
                          "index": "not_analyzed"
                      },
                      "visibility": {
                          "type": "integer",
                          "analyzer":"keyword_lowercase"
                      },
                      "userGroupAssociationCount": {
                          "type": "integer",
                          "index": "not_analyzed"
                      },
                      "associatedUserIds" :{
                        "analyzer":"keyword_lowercase",
                        "type": "string"
                      },
                      "createrFriendsId":{
                        "analyzer":"keyword_lowercase",
                        "type": "string"
                      }
}
```

and the search query is:

> {
>     "query": {
>       "query_string": {
>         "query": "new"
>       }
>     },
>     "from": 0,
>     "size": 10
>   }

Can anyone tell me "what is the problem arise here and why it occurs" it will be more helpful me to fix this issue

Comment: How do you send your query and with which client?

Comment: @Val thanks for ur response.I had been checked this query in elastic search head plugin.

Comment: Then you must use the POST method and not the GET when sending a query int he payload. Please try again.

Comment: @val but the get method used for the search API  right? .I didn't understand clearly why we using post method for search

Comment: GET should only be used when not sending any payload, otherwise POST should be used. The head plugin doesn't send any payload when using GET, so just you POST and it will work.

Comment: thaks for your response @val

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106679/discussion-between-mohan-and-val).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're sending your query with GET in the head plugin, it doesn't send any payload

So instead you should just you POST and it will work.

GET should only be used when not sending any payload and only a query in the URL (i.e. using `q=...`, otherwise POST should be used.